# Turned "E" character in titles

Tags: title

Some TV series contain a turned "E" character in their titles, such as:

- [HOMƎLAND](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1796960/)
- [ÉLITƎ](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7134908/)
- [CALIPHATƎ](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11398870/)
- [The EVƎNT](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1582459/)

(Feel free to add other examples.)

Is there some common underlying meaning to this usage, or is it just used as a "cool" thing, like a [Metal umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut)?

Comment: Was the last character in ÉLITƎ always a backwards E which *almost* makes the series logo an [ambigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram) or was it added to the series logo in the third season to note a *3*?

Comment: could it be that it's a hint that the series is about "turning" someone? Also I think that Etile means in spanish "ethics".

Comment: The Event had it's second "e" mirrored too! It usually donates either a "3" or that this is about mystery that is "off" or a show that might have mirrored themes...

Answer (score 6):

There is no underlying meaning to this - each case should be interpreted separately. Sometimes it can be a reference to 3, or to make the logo more symmetrical, or to make the word look more like a different language, or to show that something is not right, but in a different way, etc.